# awk to split the input file into 2 files(one for duplicated values and one for unique values)

Tags: awk, perl, gawk

I have an input file like below.

```
file.txt
14 2.692022 author1 0
14 2.57826 author2 1
229 2 author3 2
323 2 author4 3
514 2.0625 author5 4
```

I am trying to split the file with the duplicated values as one file and the rest of values as another file. So, for the above input, I am trying to generate files like,

```
file1.txt
14 2.692022 author1 0
14 2.57826 author2 1

file2.txt
229 2 author3 2
323 2 author4 3
514 2.0625 author5 4
```

I am not able to figure out how to use awk for this purpose.

```
awk '{print $1}' file.txt | uniq -d > file1.txt
```

The above command gives me only the duplicated values in a file. Also, it gives me only the field1 but not all the 3 fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`awk` supports direct file redirection in its syntax.

```
awk 'BEGIN{prev=""} {if($1==prev) { print $0 > "duplicates.txt"} else { print $0 > "originals.txt"}; prev=$1; }' file.txt
```

I assumed the file is already sorted. If it's not, it gets much harder.

EDIT: is this better?

```
awk 'BEGIN{prev=""; prevfull=""}
$1==prev{ if(prevfull!=""){print prevfull > "duplicates.txt"; prevfull=""}; print > "duplicates.txt"}
$1!=prev{ if(prevfull!=""){print prevfull > "originals.txt"}; prevfull=$0}
{prev=$1; } END{print prevfull}' file.txt
```

It can definitely be done better (the ifs are definitely not optimal) but it shows the general idea.

Comment: Thanks. The file is already sorted. I will check this command.

Comment: I see some values are copied to originals.txt though they are duplicate values. They are basically present in both the files.

Comment: Oh I think I misunderstood. I put the first instance in originals and the subsequent into duplicates. It can be fixed :)